# Как задавать точку трансформации transfrom scale

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, transform

Я хочу, чтобы при наведении на блок, его высота менялась с помощью `transform: scale()`. Я не понимаю как задать точку трансформации, чтобы высота уменьшалась только с одной стороны

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.harmony {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 100px;
  transform: scale(1, 2) translateZ(0);
  transform-origin: (100%, 100%);
  transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.harmony:hover {
  transform: scale(1, 1) translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="harmony"></div>
```

Как я хочу, чтобы работало:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.harmony {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 160px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 63px;
  transition: height .2s linear;
}

.harmony:hover {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="harmony"></div>
```

Comment: я не понял про высоту с одной стороны и какой должен быть эффект

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я добавил пример, как я хочу, чтобы работало

Comment: transform-origin: 50% 0%

Comment: без скобок и запятых

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
   .harmony {
    animation: scale-up-ver-top 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}
@keyframes scale-up-ver-top {
  0% {
transform: scaleY(0.4);
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
  100% {
transform: scaleY(1);
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://animista.net/

Comment: Спасибо, но это вопрос уже решили, оказалось, что я просто указывал `transform-origin: (100%, 100%);`, менял значения, но ничего не изменялось. Оказалось, что нужно просто не указывать скобки и запятую